# Assigning layer feature to another layer having same name in table using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layers

I have 3 groups of layers, layer names are the same in the 3 groups as shown in this image below:

[image]:

I want to make a table of 4 fields:

1. layer names of group (1),
2. layer lengths of group (1),
3. Feature count of group (2),
4. Feature count of group (3),

I am trying with this code:

```
#Create an empty table in memory and add fields
newtable = QgsVectorLayer("None", "Layer Length", "memory")
provider = newtable.dataProvider()
provider.addAttributes([QgsField('Layer Name', QVariant.String),
                        QgsField('Length', QVariant.Double),\
                        QgsField('Rl Count', QVariant.Double),\
                        QgsField('SL Count', QVariant.Double)])
newtable.updateFields()

group_names = ['group1', 'group2']

for name in group_names:
    group = root.findGroup(name)
    layers = [layer.layer() for layer in group.children()]
    
    for lyr in layers:
        total_length = sum([r.geometry().length() for r in lyr.getFeatures()])
        f = QgsFeature()
        f.setAttributes([lyr.name(), total_length])
        provider.addFeatures([f])

group_names = ['RL', 'SL']

for name in group_names:
    group = root.findGroup(name)
    layers = [layer.layer() for layer in group.children()]
    
    for lyr in layers:
        Featurecount = lyr.featureCount() 
        f = QgsFeature()
        f.setAttributes([lyr.name(), Featurecount])
        provider.addFeature(f)
    
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(newtable)
```

the code gives me the following table, How can I edit the code to assign the feature count numbers to the layer having the same name? as here in this image:

[image: table I get]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume all layers in the groups have the same order

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()

#Create an empty table in memory and add fields
newtable = QgsVectorLayer("None", "Layer Length", "memory")
provider = newtable.dataProvider()
provider.addAttributes([QgsField('Layer Name', QVariant.String),
                        QgsField('Length', QVariant.Double),
                        QgsField('RL Count', QVariant.Double),
                        QgsField('SL Count', QVariant.Double)])
newtable.updateFields()

group = root.findGroup("group1")
rl = root.findGroup("RL")
sl = root.findGroup("SL")
stack = [group.children(), rl.children(), sl.children()]

for glyr, rlyr, slyr in zip(*stack):
    total_length = sum([r.geometry().length() for r in glyr.layer().getFeatures()])
    rl_count = rlyr.layer().featureCount()
    sl_count = slyr.layer().featureCount()
    
    f = QgsFeature()
    f.setAttributes([glyr.name(), total_length, rl_count, sl_count])
    provider.addFeatures([f])
    
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(newtable, False)
root.insertLayer(0, newtable)
```

[image]

Comment: It's exactly what I'm looking for, It will help me a lot, I'm thankful for you, bro!